# python: how to delete blank lines?

Tags: python, string, blank-line

The input is designed to contain multiple lines of answer from the user, all the white spaces at the start need to be deleted, I have down that by using line.strip(). However, I cannot figure out a way to delete the input blank lines between each line of the answer.

```py
print("after press enter and add a quit at end of your code")
print("copy and paste your code here")
text = ""
stop_word = "end"
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == stop_word:
        break
    text += "%s\n" % line.strip()
print(text)
```

Comment: can you give an example input, output ?

Comment: @Asif my problem is solved, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect a blank line in your code by checking the value of the line.

```
if line == "":
    # start the next iteration without finishing this one
    continue
```

The following code discards a line if it is empty:

```py
print("after press enter and add a quit at end of your code")
print("copy and paste your code here")
text = ""
stop_word = "end"
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == "":
        continue

    if line.strip() == stop_word:
        break
    text += "%s\n" % line.strip()
print(text)
```